# Store absolute URL for selenium test using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have a html file which stores which suppose to store the absoluteUrl whose content is this :

```
<html>
<head><title>Root URL variable</title></head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">Root URL variable</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>

<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{window.location;}</td>
    <td>rootUrl</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table> 
</body>
</html>
```

The problem arises when I try to replace `window.location` with `var loc = window.location;`  I am getting this error

> Command execution failure. Please search the forum at http://clearspace.openqa.org for error details from the log window.  The error message is: eval(match[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery)) is undefined

That is the first issue. Second issue is that I would like to get the absolute path using javascript and try to store as the rootUrl variable. Any solution suggestions will be handy(If the first problem is solved I am planning to try solution similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery) by Neville Bonavia i.e.

```
function getAbsolutePath() {
var loc = window.location;
var pathName = loc.pathname.substring(0, loc.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
return loc.href.substring(0, loc.href.length - ((loc.pathname + loc.search + loc.hash).length - pathName.length));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Selenium is running `this` refers to the Selenium object which means that you won't have direct access to `window` or `document`.

To get direct access you will need to do `this.browserbot.getUserWindow()`. That returns you the `window` object on the page and then you can make your usual calls.

e.g.

```
var window = this.browserbot.getUserWindow();
return window.location;
```

Comment: Right. This is what I ended up using 'this.browserbot.baseUrl' as it's path doesn't change for the length of the test suite.